# Set file association on .pdf files in midnight commander

Tags: pdf, mc

I've been looking all over the net, but did not find anything useful.

How would one set default program for opening `.pdf` files with `zathura` for example, in `midnight commander`. I know I have to edit `mc.ext` file, but there are no docs available that says something about the format of entry, which would be used.

Answer (score 4):

Need to find in mc.ext next strings.

```
# PDF
type/^PDF
    Open=(see %f &)
    #Open=(acroread %f &)
    #Open=(ghostview %f &)
    View=%view{ascii} pdftotext %f -
```

And next change first string `Open=(see %f &)` by something that -->
`Open=(zathura %f &)`

Answer (score 0):

`/home/<user>/mc.ext` accessible also in 'mc` via hotkey F9 (Main menu) -> Commands -> Edit extension file